# How I can get Jsp Struts property value in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts-1

Currently I have One Jsp page in that same page I have written jquery Autocomplete, and I need to pass that property value up to action class.

jQuery:

```
$("#mednameautobox").autocomplete("/ConsultationAutoCompleteAction.do?mode=getAutoCompletionList&parameter=Med Name&forvalue"+document.getElementById("FormId").value);
```

JSP:

```
<td>
<html:text styleId="mednameautobox" property="mednameautobox" value="SEARCH MEDICINE NAME" styleClass="textBox textBoxMedium" disabled="<%=viewmode%>"  onblur="javascript:searchfromselectbox('Med Name');"/>
</td>
<td width="20%" class="formLabel">Form:<span class="mandatorySymbol">*</span></td>
    <!-- <td class="formLabel">City: </td> -->
    <td>
    <html:select name="frmPatientDetails" property ="formlist" styleId="FormId" styleClass="selectBox selectBoxMedium" disabled="<%=viewmode%>" onchange="getDropDown('medicine','MedicineId')">
    <html:option value="">Select from list</html:option>
    <html:optionsCollection name="alformlist" label="cacheDesc" value="cacheId"/>
    </html:select>
    </td>
```

Action class :

```
String FormValue=request.getParameter("forvalue");
                System.out.println("form value in AutoCompleteAction:  "+FormValue);
```

But the FormValue value I am getting null.
suggest me any another way to achieve it or correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should URL-encode your URL
2. You should make sure `forvalue` is URL-safe (handled by #1)
3. Ultimately the issue is how you retrieve the `<select>` value

To get an HTML `<select>` value you can't simply ask for the value:

```
var selector = document.getElementById('id_of_select');
var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
```